# User interaction conflict during SetTimeout in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress (Javascript) plugin that alters text fields based on user interaction with an HTML5 slider. One of its effects is to reveal a `<span>` string one character at a time using SetTimeout to create a delay (a few ms) so the effect is perceptible. I'm accomplishing this by getting the DOM element's contents and then rebuilding it one character at a time.

The problem is that since SetTimeout is aynsynchronous, the user can potentially move the slider faster than a single reveal loop can complete, resulting in half-empty DOM elements that never get corrected.

Is there a way to prevent this, or alternatively, a way to accomplish the task that avoids the conflict altogether? I have tried turning off the EventListener (for the HMTL5) at various points in the delay loop but cannot find a place that avoids the issue. The other possibility is to load *all* the `<span>` contents into arrays in order to retain intact copies of everything ... but something tells me there's a better way to do it that I don't know.

Here is example code. Initialize() is called when the HTML page involved loads.

```
function Initialize () {
   document.getElementById(name).addEventListener('input', UpdateSlider);    
  }

function UpdateSlider() 
{  if ( 
      // conditions
     ) 

{ var cols = document.getElementsByClassName(attr+i);                   
            RevealTextLines (cols);    
    } 

// 'delay' is a global variable to set the delay length

function RevealTextLines (cols)
 {      
        [].forEach.call(cols, function(el) {
          var snippet = el.innerHTML; 
          el.innerHTML = '';
          el.style.display = 'inline';            
          (function addNextCharacter(h) {
            el.innerHTML = snippet.substr(0,h);
                h = h + numchars;
               if (h <= snippet.length) {    
                setTimeout(function() {
                               addNextCharacter(h);
                            }, delay);
                     }
            })(1);
      });

 }
```

Comment: I don't see here any code relevant to user interaction.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to keep the question concise - but I added a little more code for context.

Comment: Just define a boolean flag outside all your functions. Check it before `RevealTextLines` call; if it is not set, set it to `true`; then set it to`false` in appropriate `else` block after `if (h <= snippet.length)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boolean flag suggested above does not work in this case, but it did inspire the following solution:

Provided the number of iterations are known in advance (which in this case they are), define a global counter variable outside the functions. Before the SetTimeout loop, set it to the number of iterations and decrease it by 1 every time through. Then have the calling function proceed only when the counter's value is zero.

```
    var counter = 0;

    function Initialize () {
       document.getElementById(name).addEventListener('input', UpdateSlider);    
      }

    function UpdateSlider() 
    {  if ( counter == 0) 
   { var cols = document.getElementsByClassName(classname);                   
                RevealTextLines (cols);    
        } 

    function RevealTextLines (cols)
     {      
            [].forEach.call(cols, function(el) {
              timer = el.length;
              var snippet = el.innerHTML; 
              el.innerHTML = '';
              el.style.display = 'inline';            
              (function addNextCharacter(h) {
                el.innerHTML = snippet.substr(0,h);
                h++;
               if (h <= snippet.length) {    
                      setTimeout(function() {
                      addNextCharacter(h);
                      timer--;
                      UpdateSlider();
                         }, delay);
                     }
            })(1);
      });

 }
```

If anyone knows a more efficient solution, I would remain interested.